# Start an activity without re-load activity / layout before

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to start a new activity when you press an entry.

The current activity is a ListView with items that load automatically when scrolled (endless scrolling).

As soon as an entry is clicked, a new activity (or layout?) is to be opened (with back button in the navigation).

https://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.mp4

As in this video from Android, as soon as you click back again, the activity does not reload. Scroll position is saved + all images / entries is same

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is **Share Element Transition**

It works on Android 5.x and above

Refer [this](https://medium.com/@DeepakDroid/share-element-transition-between-recycler-view-and-fragment-8ce5084fd7a2) , [this](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity#java) or [this](https://medium.com/@aitorvs/android-shared-element-transitions-for-all-b90e9361507d) links for more detail and examples.

Answer (score 1):

use pair for this type in animation in your app :-

from fristActvity:-

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ImageViewActivity.class);
    Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
    pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(imageView, "fullImage");
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, pairs);

intent.putExtra("fullImage", imageUrl);
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

in second activity you have to set transitionName in you xml file :-

```
android:transitionName="fullImage"
```